# if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) não funciona com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou enviando informações para outra página via Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Função para enviar as informações para o arquivos processa.php 
  //via Ajax
  function envia(x){


      jQuery('#form_protocolo_' + x).submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        alert(dados);

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  "processa.php",
          data: dados,
          success: function( data )
          {
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = ( data );
          },
          error: function(data, textStatus){
            alert( textStatus );
          },

        });
        return false;
      });
  }
</script>
```

Entretanto, meu arquivo `protocolo.php`, que recebe as informações possui uma verificação: `if (isset($_POST['enviar']))`. Se o usuário clicar no botão enviar, o arquivo continua a ação.

Mas quando estou tendo a resposta em `success: function( data )` ele se comporta como se o usuário não tivesse acionado o botão Enviar, me retornando `Você não clicou no botão enviar!`, mesmo este tendo clicado nele.

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){

  //Executa a ação

} else {

  echo "Você não clicou no botão enviar!";

}
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Poste o se `HTML` também, por favor.

Comment: Primeiro: no AJAX você envia as informações para `processa.php`, mas cita um arquivo `protocolo.php`. Isso está correto? Segundo: quando você efetua uma requisição AJAX, o campo referente ao botão não é incluído, pois este só deve ser incluído pelo navegador ao processar o evento `submit` do formulário. Você precisará rever a sua condição no PHP.

Comment: Se o enviar é um botão o valor dele só vai ser enviado se tiver o atributo `name` estiver definido, o que não é a melhor forma de fazer. Para saber se foi feita uma submissão da página em `POST` é melhor testar com `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` e depois testar cada campo individualmente

Comment: Testei com if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') e funcionou. 
Obtive o resultado que esperava. Vou seguir as dicas de vocês para trabalhar da melhor forma possível. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está buscando o indice "Enviar" no array Global POST, porém esse indice não foi definido em nenhum momento, isso está em seu HTMl como name de um dos campos do seu formulário ? Faça um Isset de algum dos campos do formulário e lembre de atribuir um name para todos eles e fazer o Isset a partir do Name e não do ID ou outro atibuto.

Comment: Sim Sim. Todos são feitos a partir do atributo name.
<button type='submit' onclick='envia($id_protocolo_doc);' name='enviar' value='enviar' style='display:none;' id='botao_receber_$id_protocolo_doc' >RECEBER</button>